# App works fine on AVD but not on Nexus7 tablet

Tags: android

When I run my app it works fine on my AVD but when I tried it on tablet Nexus 7 , I am not able to enter values in one `EditText` view. Following is the entry in the debug log after each click on `EditText` view in tablet.

```
04-12 14:48:37.080: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10180): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Entry for this textview in layout file is

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/joinCanvasPasswordTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint="Canvas Password"

        android:textColor="#000"
         />
```

log file

```
04-12 15:39:45.790: I/dalvikvm-heap(7093): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.452MB for 1606416-byte allocation
04-12 15:39:45.830: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 10669K/12852K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
04-12 15:39:45.890: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 10668K/12852K, paused 8ms+6ms, total 60ms
04-12 15:39:57.990: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 0
04-12 15:39:57.990: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 1
04-12 15:39:58.000: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 2
04-12 15:39:58.010: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1749K, 30% free 9032K/12848K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-12 15:39:58.010: I/dalvikvm-heap(7093): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.385MB for 1606416-byte allocation
04-12 15:39:58.060: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 10601K/12848K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
04-12 15:39:58.080: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13912): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-12 15:39:58.120: I/InputAttributes(7093): InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified
04-12 15:39:58.130: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 44K, 18% free 10603K/12848K, paused 5ms+10ms, total 70ms
04-12 15:39:58.200: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 0
04-12 15:39:58.210: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 1
04-12 15:39:58.210: D/CANVASLIST VIEW ROW(13912): 2
04-12 15:39:58.210: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1636K, 30% free 9031K/12848K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
04-12 15:39:58.210: I/dalvikvm-heap(7093): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.384MB for 1606416-byte allocation
04-12 15:39:58.260: D/dalvikvm(7093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 18% free 10600K/12848K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 49ms
04-12 15:39:58.260: D/dalvikvm(7093): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
04-12 15:39:58.260: D/dalvikvm(7093): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
```

Comment: post total logcat & share your code

Comment: there's nothing special in logcat, i posted it above

Comment: problem solved :) by setting inputType="textPersonName"

Comment: Nice to hear .Happy coding